# C basic interaction over for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm doing an exercise over loops and have a doubt.

I have an array of `ints` and want to iterate all over this array the get the `sum`of the array elements. This iteraction must be done, in each pass, sum the first element and the last, on the second iteraction, sum the second element and the last element minus 1 and so on.

If I have an array with a even number of elements I'm doing this way:

```
int main(){
    int i,sum=0,arraySize=10;
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4,4,4,7,8,9,10};

    for (i=0;i <arraySize/2;i++){
        sum+=array[i] + array[arraySize-i-1];
    }

    printf("The sum is %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

but if I have an odd number I'm doing this:

```
int main(){
    int i,sum=0,arraySize=11;
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4,4,4,7,8,9,10,11};

    for (i=0;i <(arraySize/2)+0.5;i++){
        if (i != (arraySize/2)){
            sum+=array[i] + array[arraySize-i-1];
        }
        else{
             sum+=array[i];
        }
    }

    printf("The sum is %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: For the record, this is a bad homework assignment with no relevance to real-world programming.

Comment: @Lundin I disagree. It teaches you programming on a different level. Judging by the difficulty this is an introduction to programming and concepts. The hardest part is formalizing a pragmatic approach at reaching a certain answer/solution. Even though the assignment is not realistic, it teaches you this formalization process. You don't start teaching programming by computing the convex hull of a point-set, if you understand what I mean.

Comment: @Yuri It is not bad because the program purpose isn't realistic, but rather because the requirements don't make sense and there is no room to question them. There is no reason why someone must calculate the sum in this odd manner. Had the assignment been "find out whether a string is a palindrome or not", then the algorithm would have ended up very similar to this in a natural manner. Then you wouldn't only need a pragmatic approach to reach the answer, but you would also have to question the spec and gather the requirements (are capital letters/spaces allowed etc). Engineer vs code monkey.

Comment: @Lundin on the other hand, formulating a palindrome is so incredibly well known that a single google search would provide a huge number of hits, whilst a little rephrasement such as used above effectively solves the same problem, but is harder to google and thus forces the students to try and solve it themselves.

Comment: @Yuri A good programming teacher would have the student explain their program, line per line. If they don't understand the code, it is going to be blatantly obvious just after a few lines. As long as the student knows what the program is doing, then there is no harm in using Google; quite the opposite. If you Google for code you might come across some state of the art algorithm that the student can learn from, instead of making some ugly, inefficient buggy mess of their own. Also, real-world engineers who re-invent the wheel in every project aren't going to be popular by their manager.

Comment: @Lundin talking from my teaching experience at a university, I can guarantee you that sometimes the people with the best explanations understand the least. At this stage people need to learn by doing things themselves, and are in no way capable to understand much smarter algorithms. Please do note that I *fully* agree with you that you need to avoid re-inventing the wheel all the time in the real world. However, when you've just started learning to code there are times where you have to come up with solutions of your own.

Comment: @Lundin The only good homework assignments aren't homework. It's when you are responsible for production code; that code goes screaming into the weeds; and you're the person who has to clean up the mess you made. But I tend to agree with you on one point, which is don't give stiff, meaningless exercises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
 for(i=0, j= arraySize-1; i <= j; i++,j--){
   sum += array[i];
   if(i!=j){ sum+= array[j]; }
 }
```

Comment: @jamesdlin you are right. I was a bit too quick. Initialize to `arraySize - 1` seems the correct way to go. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that we could do the for loop the way you posted. This way is much simpler...

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this - avoid floats unless you really need them:

```
for (i=0; i < (arraySize / 2) + (arraySize & 1); i++) {
```

`(arraySize & 1)` is 1 for odd and 0 for even values.

Or even easier:

```
for (i = 0; i < (arraySize + 1) / 2; i++) {
```

Comment: It'd be simpler just to check `i < (arraySize + 1) / 2`.

Comment: Except, you don't need to calculate the number of iterations at each  loop, it is a fixed constant.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version optimized for readability as well as a minimum of branches/comparisons:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int calc_sum_in_weird_manner (const int* array, size_t n)
{
  int sum=0;
  const int* begin = &array[0];
  const int* end   = &array[n-1];

  while(begin < end)
  {
    sum += *begin + *end;
    begin++;
    end--;
  }

  if(begin == end) /* odd number */
  {
    sum += *begin;
  }

  return sum;
}


int main()
{
  const int array[] = {1,2,3,4,4,4,7,8,9,10,11};
  int sum;

  sum = calc_sum_in_weird_manner (array,
                                  sizeof(array)/sizeof(int));

  printf("The sum is %d.\n", sum);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
krithika.595> cat file1.cc
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{     
int i,sum=0,arraySize=10;     
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,4,4,7,8,9,10};
int j;
for (i=0,j=(arraySize-1);i<=j;i++,j--)
{         
if(i==j)
sum+=array[i];
else
sum+=array[i] + array[j];     
}
cout <<sum<<endl;
}
krithika.596> ./a.out
52
krithika.597>
```

Comment: The answer is supposed to be C, not C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0;(i <arraySize/2)||(array[i]==array[arraySize-i-1]);i++){
        if (array[i]==array[arraySize-i-1]) {
             sum+=array[i];

        }else{

        sum+=array[i] + array[arraySize-i-1];
        }
    }


    printf("The sum is %d\n", sum);
```

Comment: This is both hard to read and inefficient. You don't need to calculate the number of iterations each time in the loop, it's a constant. You also don't need 3 different comparisons, one per loop should be sufficient.